# Is there a system broadcast for when a user toggles the "Background restriction" for an app in Android?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

To toggle "Background restriction" in an Android phone (Oreo+), a user can go to:
App's settings -> Advance -> Battery -> Background restriction.

If disabled, the app will no longer be able to run background services while the app is in the background.  This will save battery.

However, this is causing a crash when the app goes back to the foreground.

I can't find an intent broadcast action for listening for this event in the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Does anyone know how I can detect for this permission change?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [isBackgroundRestricted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#isBackgroundRestricted()) API.

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onCreate: activityManager.isBackgroundRestricted() = " + activityManager.isBackgroundRestricted());
    }
```

And show some sort of dialog to the user to tell them that they need to change it back.